# Webscrape into Visual Studio VB Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2012, web-scraping

I've got a form that looks like the following:
[image]

I would like to simply enter the stock, click the get price button, have the button return the price it scraped.

I'm experienced with Excel VBA and how to scrape but not so much how it translates into Visual Studio (VB language)

Below is what I've got for the form so far. I attempted to add the HTML document and Internet controls methods already. So far I can get it to successfully open and shut internet explorer--I just can't get it to scrape anything. It just errors out, and I can't dim internet explorer as an HTML object. Below is the code so far...

```
Public Class Form1

Dim stockBox As Single
Dim price As Single



Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

End Sub


'Private Function READYSTATE_COMPLETE() As Object
'Throw New NotImplementedException()
' End Function

' Private Sub DoEvents()
'Throw New NotImplementedException()
' End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim px As Single



    ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & (TextBox1.Text))

        'Do
        '  DoEvents
        'Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        'Dim doc As HtmlDocument
        'doc = ie.document
        While ie.readyState <> 4

        End While


        On Error Resume Next

        px = ie.GetElementById("yfs_l84_" & (TextBox1.Text)).InnerText



        ie.Quit




    End With


    Label3.Text = px



End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Instead of opening IE, try adding a Webbrowser control to your form, set its URL, Navigate, then you have access to the Document object and HTML elements

Comment: This helped out, thanks!